# How can I find out the name of a particular permission?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

I'm trying to give permission to a role on my Drupal site by using the Drush command.

The permission to "Article: create new content" should be given to the `test-role` role.

```sh
drush role-add-perm 'test-role' '#####'
```

I'm not able to figure out what to write in the `####` field.

How do I write "Article: create new content" in the Drush command?

Comment: Note that you can set all configuration you want in the back-end (permissions, create content types and similar) and then export that configuration to yml config files (drush cex), transfer the files and then import again (drush cim).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew the export and import option was available but I have 3 environments, So each and every time after implement on dev env and don't want to do export and import on other env instead using pipeline I will execute the drush commands.
So I ask once again do we have Drush commands to create new content types? 
:)

Comment: You should keep your config files on git so when config is imported and checked on dev env you should merge that merge request into other envs and re-import config there. No need to export again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Devel to get the machine name of the permission you want. Enable "Display machine names of permissions and modules" in Devel settings and the permission machine name will show when you hover on it in the permissions page. Each content type has a different permission so you will need to get the specific one you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This really helped, I want to create new content type(Structure - > content types ->Add content type) using Drush comannd, How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

One way to find out the name of the permission is inspecting the page markup on the permissions page. There you'll see something like `<tr data-drupal-selector="edit-permissions-create-article-content" class="odd">`. `create-article-content` translates to `create article content`.

```sh
drush role:perm:add test-role 'create article content'
```

Seems you are still on an older Drush version there it might be `drush rap test-role 'create article content'`. Better update your Drush.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful, I want to create new content type(Structure - > content types ->Add content type) using Drush comannd, How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @ReddyRohit – Upvote and accept my answer and ask a new question.